# Differentiate between 'account types' in Django

Tags: python, django

Thanks in advance if you're reading this... I'm a High School student working on a web application using Django, to help students find internships, and facilitate parents posting internship offers -- a sort of marketplace if you will.

I'm trying to create a profile/account page for the users but I need a way to differentiate between whether the account logged in is a Student or Employer so that I can use views.py to generate a page appropriate to their account.

In models.py, I have two different profile types which can be associated with a user account (handled by django.contrib.auth), see below for reference.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profilePic = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Student Profile'
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username}'s Profile"

class Employer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profilePic = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Unspecified')
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Employer/Parent Profile'
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username}'s Profile"
```

In my views.py page, I'm trying to create a view for the account/profile that can detect whether the currently logged-in user's profile is linked to either the 'Student' or 'Parent' model and serve a page accordingly. I've tried a very rudimentary approach, as below, but unsurprisingly it's not working.

```
def account(request):
if user.student.username == True:
    context = 'Account: Student'
    return render(request, 'users/studentprofile.html', context)

elif user.employer.username == True:
    context = 'Account: Employer'
    return render(request, 'users/employer.html', context)
```

I was wondering if anyone had a suggestion as to how I can best accomplish this... apologies in advance is this approach is poorly structured or against the status-quo of Django Programming, I'm a complete beginner!

Thanks in advance all :)

Comment: You have to work on one error at a time (read and post the error message that Django gives you). You have multiple errors in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Morteza Afshari said, you should reorganize your models to include a boolean field.

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profilePic = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Profile'
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username}'s Profile"
```

This follows the DRY principle much better than your prior code because now we're not repeating fields like user, profilePic, etc.

Now we can rewrite your views.py like this:

```
def account(request):
if user.is_student:
   context = 'Account: Student'
   return render(request, 'users/studentprofile.html', context)

else:
   context = 'Account: Employer'
   return render(request, 'users/employer.html', context)
```

Comment: This is wonderful and much cleaner than before, thank you very much. I'm in the process of implementing this, but I keep getting the error "type object 'User' has no attribute 'is_student'', any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have any pre existing users?

Comment: I've wiped the existing profiles which would have been configured without the 'is_student' attribute and created a new one but I'm still getting the same error. I have a feeling that Django can't find the attribute 'is_student' as the model that contains this is just an extension of the Django.auth.contrib user model, it's not inherently associated. Is this correct? Potentially I'll need to override the default 'user' model in settings.py for this to take affect.

Answer (score 0):

it would be better if you posted your exception/error alongside your code

but here's some hint:
context parameter passed to render function should be a dictionary not an string

```
context = {'Account: Student'}
```

and you should access to user with *request.user* not just *user*

if problems above didn't solve your problem
add these two lines of code at the beginning of your function:

```
print(request.user.student)
print(request.user.employer)
```

Comment: Good answer

But context must be a dict

`context  = {'Account' : 'student'}`

Comment: well that's what i said in that code context is string look at the question
so i corrected it and said it should be dictionary instead of string

Answer (score 0):

You can have an boolean field in user model like `is_student` and fill it during sign in. It can be `null=True` and null when user signed out.

If you have jwt token, you can store additional data in token to check where it comes from, or either store user current role in its cookie. Get us more data about your site structure for more related answers. (Data about authentication system, database structure or any more structural behaviors)

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion! I really appreciate it :)